# PHP Mysqli return array from JOIN (alias as array key)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Ok so I have this query, which works quite good, but it doesn't return what i want to.

```
SELECT acc.*, fin.* 
FROM consumers acc
LEFT JOIN finances fin ON fin.uid = acc.uid 
WHERE acc.id = '$userID';
```

This returns an array (in php) where the key is 0 and all the columns (from both tables) are under the same array.

What I want to achieve is get 2 arrays, 1 with columns from first table, and another 1 with columnds from the second table.

Basically i'm trying to get a multidimensional array out of 1 query.

Comment: `account` should be `acc`

Comment: There's no way to do what you want automatically.  When you're in your `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc())` loop, assign the columns into two different arrays.

Comment: despite that little type when i rewrote the query here, still doesn't work.

Comment: It was just a comment, not intended as an answer to the question.

Comment: There's only 1 row returned, and all the columns are grouped together in the same array. I can't really do that.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two arrays after reading the row.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$acc = array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], ...);
$fin = array($row['col6'], $row['col7'], ...);
```

where `col1,`col2`, ... are the columns from`consumer`, and`col6`,`col7`, ... are the columns from`$finances`.

A way to do it without listing all the column names is with `array_slice()`

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$acc = array_slice($row, 0, $number_of_consumer_columns);
$fin = array_slice($row, $number_of_consumer_columns, $number_of_finances_columns);
$table3 = array_slice($row, $number_of_consumer_columns + $number_of_finances_columns, $number_of_table3_columns);
```

You can continue this for all the tables. It would be straightforward to put this into a function that takes an array of all the column counts, and returns a 2-dimensional array containing each table's data.

Comment: If i wanted to do it the long way i could just run separate queries for each of the tables.

Comment: But then you'd have to do two queries instead of one.

Comment: Would be still shorter than creating the arrays myself as the tables have around 25 columns each.

Comment: Added another method to the answer

Comment: This is still not good enough. That's about 1 part of my code as there are just slightly over 10 tables.

Comment: I've shown how to do it for 3 tables, it's easily extended to an arbitrary number, and you can put that into a function that takes an array of column counts.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with a fast solution:

```
<?php

            $tableData = array( 'account'       =>  'consumers', 'finance'      =>  'consumers_finance', 'household'        =>  'consumers_household', 'media'          =>  'consumers_media', 'medical'        =>  'consumers_medical', 'shopping'     =>  'consumers_shopping', 'social'      =>  'consumers_social', 'technology'    =>  'consumers_technology', 'transport'     =>  'consumer_transport', 'b2b'         =>  'consumers_b2b', 'employment'   =>  'consumer_employment_status');

            $openAccount = array();

            foreach($tableData as $key => $table)
            {
                $whichWhere = $db->doQuery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table` LIKE 'uid'");
                $whichWhere = (isset($whichWhere[0]['Field'])) ? 'uid' : 'id';

                $getDetails = $db->getArray("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $whichWhere = '$userID'");

                if(isset($getDetails[0]))
                {
                    $openAccount[$key] = $getDetails[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    $getDetails = $db->doQuery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");

                    foreach($getDetails as $column)
                    {
                        $openAccount[$key][$column[0]] = '';
                    }
                }
            }

?>
```

This will help me deal with tables that have no entry for uid so that i wont have to run double checks on array to avoid undefined indexes.